# where to host express api that communicates with smart contract to be fully decentralised?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, nodejs, decentralization, express

I need to host  express api that communicates with smart contract to be fully decentralised. Any to host it decentralised.

Comment: The smart contract itself should really be all the "decentralized API" you need, if you expose the required data through public functions. Or am I misunderstanding the question ?

Comment: I have and express app that perform some little logic and communicate with smart contract using web3. This Express app is on aws ec2 right now i want it move to some p2p decentralised hosting solution.hope that gives you a more clear idea about it. thanks @SimonR